# Defining both CreateProjection and CreateMap

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-6.0

In my project I use Entity Framework for ORM, and Dto classes for api responses. I use Automapper to map between the two.

When I need to directly fetch the Dtos from the EF queryables, I do a final `ProjectTo<>` on my query and everything is fine.

But there are many times that I have an already materialized object from entity framework and I need to Map it to its Dto equivalent. In this case I use `Map<>` instead of `ProjectTo<>` since I have an instance in memory and not an IQueryable that translates to SQL.

I have registered both Projection and Map when I created the Automapper profile like this:

```
CreateMap<UserSession, Models.UserSession>(); // used when mapping between instances
CreateProjection<UserSession, Models.UserSession>(); // used when mapping on EF LINQ expressions
```

That should be enough for Automapper to understand that when I use ProjectTo I want the Projection mapping and when I use Map I want the instance mapping.

But, instead, when I have a materialized `UserSession` object (the type registered with Entity Framework), and want to map it to a `Models.UserSession` object (my Dto) I get this response.

```
CreateProjection works with ProjectTo, not with Map.
```

So, how can I register both map and projection for the same types in Automapper?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you *have* to use `CreateMap`. `CreateProjection` explicitly disables `Map`. `CreateMap` allows both.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere clearly?

Comment: Yes, in the upgrade guide.