# AutoMapper: What is the difference between CreateMap and CreateProjection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, mapping, automapper, blazor-server-side

I am looking for an explanation of the difference between CreateMap/CreateProjection in automapper and ProjectTo/MapTo by relation.
I just got started with the library and I am having trouble understanding what to use when. I partially understand that ProjectTo has some relation to LINQ and can be used for entire collections? I wish to use this library in a Blazor Server Side project.

I am also looking into these two libraries as I am using EF Core:

- https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection
- https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore

But as I am new to the library I think it is a good idea to start with the base first before moving on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TL;DR**

> If you don’t use `Map`, just `ProjectTo`, you should use `CreateProjection` instead of `CreateMap`. That way you’ll use only the API subset supported by `ProjectTo` and start-up should be faster.

> `CreateProjection` explicitly disables `Map`. `CreateMap` allows both.

So if you need only entity -> DTO mapping via ORM (like Entity Framework) and `ProjectTo` then use `CreateProjection`, otherwise use `CreateMap`.

**Details**

As written in the [docs](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) if you are working with ORM based on `IQueryable` you can use `ProjectTo` so the AutoMapper+ORM pair can generate a proper SQL statement instead of fetching the whole entity into memory (if your are not mapping in one-to-one fashion this can have positive effect on performance) and mapping it client side:

```cs
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    cfg.CreateProjection<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>()
    .ForMember(dto => dto.Item, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Item.Name)));

public List<OrderLineDTO> GetLinesForOrder(int orderId)
{
  using (var context = new orderEntities())
  {
    return context.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.OrderId == orderId)
             .ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>(configuration).ToList();
  }
}
```

> The `.ProjectTo<OrderLineDTO>()` will tell AutoMapper’s mapping engine to emit a select clause to the `IQueryable` that will inform entity framework that it only needs to query the Name column of the Item table, same as if you manually projected your `IQueryable` to an `OrderLineDTO` with a `Select` clause.

Due to the nature of the `ProjectTo` it is much more limited in what it can actually map/do (not everything can be turned into SQL).

Read more:

1. [What is the difference between IQueryable and IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252785/what-is-the-difference-between-iqueryablet-and-ienumerablet)
2. [Defining both `CreateProjection` and `CreateMap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72920666/2501279)

   > `CreateProjection` explicitly disables `Map`. `CreateMap` allows both.
3. [11.0 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/11.0-Upgrade-Guide.html#createprojection):

   > If you don’t use `Map`, just `ProjectTo`, you should use `CreateProjection` instead of `CreateMap`. That way you’ll use only the API subset supported by `ProjectTo` and start-up should be faster.
4. [12.0 Upgrade Guide](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/12.0-Upgrade-Guide.html)

   > You also cannot have for the same map/member separate configurations for `Map` and `ProjectTo`.
5. [AutoMapper ConvertUsing is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73256040/2501279)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it's generally better to use `CreateMap`.

Create map defines mappings that can be used for both `MapTo` and `ProjectTo` whereas `CreateProjection` defines mappings that only works with `ProjectTo` and effectively disables the use of `MapTo`.

Using `CreateMap` will give you the freedom to map in-memory objects and database queries (that work with `IQueryable`) directly into your chosen object.

`CreateProjection` can be used if you will only be mapping straight from DB queries

Comment: Allright, but what does it mean when I need to go the other way around? Say I fetched the data I needed using ProjectTo and made some edits to the DTO, how do I save the changes now? The CreateProjection does not seem to have a .Reverse() so do I need to create two?

Comment: @Luk164 you can use `CreateProjection` for entity -> DTO and `Map` for DTO -> entity. Personally I prefer to avoid `Reverse` unless it is used for simple one-to-one mappings without any customization.

Comment: @GuruStron Thx. Right now my DTOs are mostly just 1:1 copies with the backwards navigation parameters removed so that my DataGrid does not do stupid stuff. I did not really perform any flattening yet and I do not really see the point in BlazorSS

Comment: @GuruStron BTW what happens if I have both Map and Projection defined for the same type?

Comment: @GuruStron Correct but I think `Reverse` is fine - you just need to make sure that any mapping rules that's you've setup on in the initial definition also have a corresponding definition for the reverse.

Comment: @Luk164 you won't be able to use `MapTo` if `CreateProjection` is used.

Comment: @YungDeiza Yeah but what hapens if I have BOTH defined? Does projection get used first and map as a fallback? BTW how do I define a reverse mapping rule?

Comment: @Luk164 I have not tried it myself but as written in the upgrade to 12 version - _"You also cannot have for the same map/member separate configurations for Map and ProjectTo."_  (this is covered in my answer too).

Comment: @GuruStron Correct. It will compile though but you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: @YungDeiza _I think Reverse is fine_ - it's just a personal preference after having shot myself on the foot several times with it over the years =)

Comment: @YungDeiza yep, runtime exception was my guess =)

Comment: @GuruStron fair enough, I can see that happening.

Comment: @GuruStron I am having trouble understanding the point of CreateProjection in that case. Wouldn't that just make it very hard to save any edited objects? From what you said it sounds like a one way street to me as I cannot have a mapping to go back to original DOM object.

Comment: @GuruStron Or do I just need to do a CreateProjection<A, B> and CreateMap<B, A>?

Comment: @Luk164 _"Wouldn't that just make it very hard to save any edited objects"_ - why? You just use `CreateMap` for reverse direction (DTO -> entity). As far as I understand main point of `CreateProjection` is to improve startup performance (doubt that it will be that noticable in general case though) and limit the API used so reduce number of potential errors  at runtime.

Comment: @Luk164 yes, exactly.

Comment: @GuruStron Ok, it is all starting to make sense to me now. Thank you both